# OnOverListener doesn't work

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm trying to use the new event onHover. I look the sample, the documentation...and nothing works. The onHover event should be done by a mouse pointer.

I create a simple xml file containing 1 LinearLayout and 2 buttons inside.

My java code is following

```
  findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1).setOnHoverListener(new OnHoverListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onHover(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.e("tag", "tag");
            return false;
        }


    });
```

LinearLayout1 is my linearlayout containing button. onHover is never called.

I tried a lot of stuff without success.

Let me know if you have an idea.

Comment: does onHover even exist for mobile device. ?

Comment: Android is not only available on mobile device :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `View` that contains sub views, the subViews callbacks get called first.

if you have a button in your `LinearLayout`, all events are being called on the button and all the other views first, and only if all the sub views return `false`, only then, the event will be called on the parent view.

you should return false from all other subviews first before activating the `onHover`

Comment: If I want a hover on a simple button without layout it's the same. I tried to return false for the button but it's the same, Hover is not catched by my layout.

Comment: I have set `setOnHoverListener` on `ImageView` and still it doesn't work, do you know what causes that might make it doesn't work?